# jQuery sortable opening link on drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

I am having an issue with a sortable element when dropping. I have it set up to have an image that acts as a link, it covers the entire sortable area. Basically you can sort and arrange the images, click them to open the links, or drag them to a drop zone to remove them.

I have this working mostly, except that in Firefox, the link opens when dropping the element (only in the drop zone). I do not have this issue neither in Internet Explorer (8) nor Chrome.

Here are some code snippets:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.Droppable').droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(ui.draggable).remove();
        }
    });
    $("#ElementsArea").sortable();
});

<ul id="ElementsArea">
<li id="1" value="google" class="ui-state-default"><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="Images/placeholderblack.png" /></a></li>
<li id="2" value="yahoo" class="ui-state-default"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank"><img src="Images/placeholderyellow.png" /></a></li>
<li id="3" value="bing" class="ui-state-default"><a href="http://www.bing.com" target="_blank"><img src="Images/placeholderblack.png" /></a></li>
<li id="4" value="nhl" class="ui-state-default"><a href="http://www.nhl.com" target="_blank"><img src="Images/placeholderyellow.png" /></a></li>
<li id="5" value="mlb" class="ui-state-default"><a href="http://www.mlb.com" target="_blank"><img src="Images/placeholderblack.png" /></a></li>
<li id="6" value="nfl" class="ui-state-default"><a href="http://www.nfl.com" target="_blank"><img src="Images/placeholderyellow.png" /></a></li>
<li id="7" value="tsn" class="ui-state-default"><a href="http://www.tsn.ca" target="_blank"><img src="Images/placeholderblack.png" /></a></li>
```

and the CSS (not really important but figured I'd add it):

```css
#ElementsArea
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 800px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

#ElementsArea li
{
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; 
    padding: 1px; 
    float: left; 
    width: 125px; 
    height: 125px; 
    text-align: center;
}

.Droppable
{
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; 
    padding: 1px; 
    float: left; 
    width: 125px; 
    height: 125px; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: care to provide a http://jsfiddle.net for that ?

Comment: I can try to a little later, but atm I can add that its my environment in some way, or a newer Firefox issue, as I tried another computer with FF 13.0.1 and the issue wasn't present, my computer on 15.0.1 is having the issue EDIT: Updated that computer to 15.0.1 and it now experiences the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that in Firefox it opens the link (using your code) after dropping in the drop zone. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jur4x/c9ads/2/).

This can be fixed if you use object's clone in sortable. [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/c9ads/5/).

```
$("#ElementsArea").sortable({helper: 'clone'});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and thanks for setting up the fiddle too!

Comment: Welcome :) But next time try to provide fiddle by youself ;)